# Open mobile camera by clicking a button through web browser

Tags: html, mobile

I want to open mobile camera when I clicked a button from browser. Below there is an image what i want to do.
[This is an image what i have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaInT.png)

I can choose file from local and also want to add from camera.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
           <input type="file" name="uploadedfile" accept="image/*" capture="camera">  
           <input type="submit" value="Upload">  
        </form>
```

I tried above code for opening camera and it is from [How to access a mobile's camera from a web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581081/how-to-access-a-mobiles-camera-from-a-web-app) .
Now please help me to show camera on mobile through Browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open phone camera from HTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44264211/how-to-open-phone-camera-from-html-page)

Comment: It looks similar but I don't want from app. I want to open camera on browser only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an `input[type="file"]` field you can pick a file, or ask the device to record a media. It will always open an app or a prompt to choose an app. If you want to stay in the browser you need to use the [MediaStream Recording API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API) but it is not fully supported yet. For now, it is not working in iOS so either way, you have to open up the default camera app.

If you want to take photos you can try the [MediaStream Image Capture API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Image_Capture_API). But it is still just an experimental technology which won't work in most of the current browsers.

You can find some examples here:

- [Taking still photos with WebRTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos) - MDN
- [ImageCapture.takePhoto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageCapture/takePhoto) - MDN
- [Take Photos and Control Camera Settings](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/imagecapture) - Google developers
- [Access the camera interactively](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/capturing-images#access_the_camera_interactively) - Google developers

I hope the links above can help you

Comment: Hi, do you have any experience with mediastream image capture API?

Comment: I've played with it already but only for practice. However, I have work experience with videos without leaving the browser.

Comment: Hi, Ikarasz. Can you share your experience with me?

Comment: I have extended the answer with some links, hopefully it will help. You can find demo pages in the first two links, like: https://simpl.info/imagecapture/

Comment: Thank you. If you need some others, I can help you. You can call me here. Thanks again

Comment: I checked simpl.info/imagecapture. And on my local I can't run it. I have to make some details on my local, I think. Do you know what I have to do?

Comment: Did you try it in chrome? As the page says it works only in chrome